# Role Based Blazor Authorization on page load

Tags: authentication, blazor, roles

I hope you guys can assist me, I am unable to get the role based authorization to work on first page load in my application.

I am writing a server side blazor app with custom authorization handler where I add Role claims to the User Identity object and this works fine.

In my razor page, I set the [Authorize] attribute which shows the page if the user is authenticated which is expected.

But if I add a role to the attribute like [Authorize(Roles = "User")] it fails on page refresh, clicking another menu item in the app then seems to apply the roles correctly and then it works.

In the App.razor file, I put a break point and inspected the context.User.Identity to find out that the claims had not yet been added yet.

```
<NotAuthorized>
  @if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      <p>You do not have sufficient rights to view this page...</p>
    }
    else
    {
      <NotLoggedIn></NotLoggedIn>
    }
 </NotAuthorized>
```

My custom authorization handler is only adding the role claims after this.

I have changed the order of the request pipeline in the startup.cs file around a it looks like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
```

The code in ConfigureServices is as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "Bearer");
                defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.AddRequirements(new AppSettingsAuthRequirement(Configuration));
                options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
            });
```

Thanks for you time!

Comment: Can you add some more code regarding authorization? Also mention how did you create the project, is it the default template or did you make the authentication yourself?

Comment: Hi, I have added more from Startup.cs, ConfigureServices. Authentication works fine, it just seems to be called after the Page is rendered on the first load. Then after that the claims are loaded so its fine.